# Calculating the Velocity of a vector

Tags: vectors, kinematics

I don't know why I am finding this so difficult to understand. I have a vector, as follows:

$$ 
x_1 = [10, 8, 4]
$$

Now what I want to do is calculate the velocity of this vector, basically, these are a series of hand movements.

I can't seem to figure out what the equation would be, or, how I would go about calculating a small vector (1D) like this.

This is not homework, just looking for some advice.

Comment: Geometrically, the derivative of a vector $\vec{x}$ with respect to an external evolution parameter (time) is tangent to $\vec{x}$.

Comment: Your vector is constant!

Comment: To calculate or estimate the velocity you need to know the curve (or some points on) that the point lies on at different times. You have just given a single point above. Do you have a formula or more data?

Comment: @copper.hat - Hey, I have 500 vectors of size 3. So there is a lot more data, but, for each of the 1x3 vectors, I need to calculate the velocity.. So in theory I will have 500 values containing the velocity

Comment: Does each of the 500 represent the position at different times? Are the times regularly spaced, etc?

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah! Since, they are recorded/generated at different times so each of the 500 values (containing 3 vectors) will represent the time. I'm guessing from $ 0....n$ I guess?

Comment: Well, assuming that the position is sampled every $T$ (and assuming that $T$ is small enough to give a good approximation) you could try $v_i \approx {1 \over T} (x_{i+1} -x_i)$ for $i=1,...,499$.

Comment: You could also try fitting a polynomial through each coordinate of $x$ and then differentiating the result.

Comment: @copper.hat Just so that I'm clear.. $ 1 / T * (x_i+1 - xi) $ But, how will this produce 500 velocity values for each of the matrices?

Comment: I am assuming that you have 500 values $x_1,...,x_{500}$, each of which is a  3-vector. Then compute ${1 \over T} (x_{2} -x_1),{1 \over T} (x_{3} -x_2),...,{1 \over T} (x_{500} -x_{499})$ which gives 499 3-vectors. If you need you can approximate the last by repeating, it really depends on your situation.

Comment: @copper.hat This makes sense :) $T$ being 500? Sorry, I'm new to this and understanding is a little difficult

Comment: Well, it depends on where the $x_1,x_2,...$ come from. I was presuming that they were represented the position at times $0, T,2T,...,499T$, that is, sampled every $T$.

Comment: @copper.hat Essentially, these are points, or recordings from a device on a hand moving in a particular direction. It records a 3 value vector each time.. My idea is to calculate the velocities in order to show how the hand is moving in terms of speed etc..

Comment: Do you know the times at which the samples are taken, are the times spaced regularly? (If so, the spacing is the $T$ above.)

Comment: @copper.hat - Sorry, no I do not know. But I think they are regular, i.e. every time the hand is present so roughly around every millie second or maybe less! Thanks though, I'll try `T/500` and see where that get's me

Comment: If they are regularly spaced, then you just need to figure out the constant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13061/discussion-between-user1326876-and-copper-hat)

Answer (score 0):

If you have $x_1=[10,8,4]$ and $x_2=[10.3,8.2,4.5]$ as measurements taken $t$ seconds apart, the average velocity over that period is $\frac 1t[0.3,0.2,0.5]$.  So you can take two neighboring vectors, subtract them, and divide by the time interval.  If the time interval is short, you may have a lot of noise, so it may make more sense to smooth things, but start with the easy approach.